# Wrong event executes in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

This works:

```
$("#add").click( -> stack.op "add" )
$("#sub").click( -> stack.op "sub" )
```

but this doesn't:

```
for op in ['add','sub']  
  $('#' + op).click( -> stack.op op)
```

Both buttons executes the last operation, "sub".

```
Class Stack
  add: ...
  sub: ...
  op: (name) ->
    eval "this.#{name}()"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `do` construct:

```
for op in ['add', 'sub']
    do (op) ->
        $('#' + op).click( -> stack.op op)
```

It's because `for` loop does not create a closure.

Comment: cji nailed it. Remember that `for` loops don't create scope in JavaScript; only functions do. See my PragPub article, [A CoffeeScript Intervention](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention), for a bit more on `do`.